# Update window class in modal angularjs dynamically

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to change the css class of a modal which is provided in windowClass dynamically on some actions without recreating the modal, I am using $uibModal service, I have be struggling on this for sometime.

I tried this but did not work

```
       changeWindowClass(value) {
            this.scope.windowClass = value;
       }
```

scope is inject when calling

```
       $uibModal.open()
```

changeWindowClass is executed on clicking button (its being executed I checked using console.log).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty solution, value of windowClass passed is prefixed by "modal-", so what I did was to select the element with class `modal-{value}`, if you do not like using jQuery or jqLite you can use query selector like this

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(".{your class}")
```

Then simply remove the class and add new class using `removeClass()`, `addClass()`

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this.

```
$uibModal.open({
       templateUrl: 'templare.html',
       backdrop: 'static',
       keyboard: false,
       windowClass: 'zindex'
})
```

Comment: will I be able to change the zindex class later?